# Unable to select UITabBarItem after changing its position in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying `UITabBar` app in iPAD. But, I faced some challenges in UI.

**Required UI**

[image]

**My Output**

[image]

I have tried to move this `UITabBarItem` by using,

[image]

But, I unable to select the `UITabBarItem`. Kindly guide me, how to solve this ?

Comment: I would create a subclass of UITabBar and I would override `layoutSubviews()` . I guess I would have to get all bar items in a for loop and when I would have them I would set their origin to match the desired position.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej  .. I dont have subclass code. New to this. If u havin, pls post on this.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not a trivial task to get the frames of bar items, as UITabBarItem inherits from UIBarItem and NSObject only, but not UIView. I would suggest you search for "get uitabbarbutton". Once you get the frame you can change it's origin.